# what is html5 channel messaging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to html5 web sockets does anyone knows what is channel messaging in html5? I want to use web sockets in such a way that only two persons can communicate not all the persons who are connected to that web server.

Will this channel messaging concept help me in that?

Comment: Do you mean `HTML5 Web Messaging` ( http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/ ) ?

Comment: can you tell me what is cahnnel messaging in that

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using WebSocket.. there is also a good library available to support cross browser issue.. http://socket.io/#how-to-use  you should consider using it.

If you want to use pure javascript you should take a look at API doc http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Regards.